# Inter Vlan on L3 switch

Tags: switch, router, network

I do an inter-vlan L3 switch lab on Eve-ng emulator. The topology like below

[image]

And this is output from some **show** command at the L3 switch:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1422 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 09:42:06 EET Thu Nov 29 2018
!
version 15.2
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
service compress-config
!
hostname Switch
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no logging console
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone EET 2 0
!
ip routing
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.20.1 192.168.20.10
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.1 192.168.10.10
!
ip dhcp pool OfficePool
 network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.10.2
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
ip dhcp pool FactoryPool
 network 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.20.2
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Vlan10
 ip address 192.168.10.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan20
 ip address 192.168.20.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan100
 ip address 192.168.100.2 255.255.255.0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
!
!
end

Switch#sh ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is not set

      192.168.10.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.10.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan10
L        192.168.10.2/32 is directly connected, Vlan10
      192.168.20.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.20.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan20
L        192.168.20.2/32 is directly connected, Vlan20
      192.168.100.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.100.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan100
L        192.168.100.2/32 is directly connected, Vlan100


Switch#sh ip int brief
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Ethernet0/0            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Ethernet0/1            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Ethernet0/2            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Ethernet0/3            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Vlan10                 192.168.10.2    YES manual up                    up
Vlan20                 192.168.20.2    YES manual up                    up
Vlan100                192.168.100.2   YES manual up                    up
```

Let bypass from upper link of L3 switch to Net cloud part. On the Lan network, the PCs can get IP by DHCP, but I can't ping from Vlan10 to Vlan20 (or vice versa)

[image]

Try to trace from one vlan to other vlan, it seem L3 switch can't route between the two vlan.

[image]

Could you please point what I am doing wrong here, how to Vlan10 can ping to Vlan20.

Thanks for reading and pls help.

Comment: Can you ping between the vlan interfaces on the switch directly?

Comment: Ping to the interfaces Ip is OK.

Comment: To be clear: also from one vlan ip to another vlan ip on the switch? If you use extended ping?

Comment: The Pcs on Vlan10 can ping to Vlan20 gateway (192.168.20.2) and vice versa, Pcs on Vlan20 can ping to Vlan10 gateway (192.168.10.2). But Pcs (Vlan10/Vlan20) can't ping to Pcs (Vlan20/Vlan10). Phew, I don't know what wrong here.

Comment: And can PCs on Vlan10 ping other PCs on Vlan10? Just to see if icmp is allowed in their firewall :)

Comment: Yes, all PCs on same Vlan can ping each others.

Comment: Odd then indeed. What does sh ip cef  show?

Comment: FYI I've replicated part of your setup in gns3 and I can ping between the PCs just fine, so I think the emulator has some issues since I just copied your config.

Comment: This is output:  https://pastebin.com/XFBJzwPs

Comment: Nothing wrong there either. I think it must be something with the emulator or the used image. I tried with vIOS 15.2 in gns3 and with the same config and topology pinging between the VLANs works fine.

Comment: @Elias Maybe cause by the emulator. I also do the lab on packet tracer and it works well.

Comment: Sounds like that indeed. I can recommend gns3, but you have to find the images yourself. Good part is that it supports multiple vendors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't add a screenshot to a comment so here is the results I've had with that topology.

[image]